# How can I get this image effect for my website?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

This website is based on wordpress

http://www.gear-rat.com/

How can I get that image effect can anyone help me? in HTML5 and CSS3

I just started web design and am still learning by copying good websites so I can get handy with web design, ofc I'm not selling them or anything illegal

Comment: Check CSS3 animations ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That effect is done with the following code:

JavaScript:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    function tz_overlay() {

        jQuery('.post-thumb a').hover( function () {

            jQuery(this).find('.overlay').stop().animate({ opacity: 1 }, 200);

        }, function () {

            jQuery(this).find('.overlay').stop().animate({ opacity: 0 }, 200);
        });

    }

    tz_overlay();
});
```

CSS:

```
.post-thumb a span.overlay 
{
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 60%;
    display: block;
    line-height: 20px;
    z-index: 5;
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    -khtml-opacity: 0;
    -moz-opacity: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 40%;
    color: #ada89c;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="post-thumb port-thumb">
    <a href="http://www.gear-rat.com/test/portfolio/steel-riveted-box/">
        <span class="overlay" style="opacity: 0;">Steel Riveted Box</span>
        <img src="http://www.gear-rat.com/test/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/boxthumb1.jpg" alt="Steel Riveted Box" style="opacity: 1;">
    </a>                                
</div>
```

How I found the code:

I looked at the images and noticed they all had a class called `overlay`, so I looked in the .js files for any mention of `overlay` and saw it being used in the `tz_overlay` function. So I copied that function and the div surrounding an image to my website. When I opened a page with that div in it, it worked like that website so I know I had it.

It is a good idea to look around for specific indicators like that when trying to find out how something works on a website.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this with only html and css3, you don't need javascript or a javascript library.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>hello world</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        div#tmp{
            background-color: #A36333;
            height: 100px;
            width: 100px;
        }
        div#tmp div{            
            background-color: #000000;
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
            color: #ffffff;
            line-height: 100px;
            vertical-align: middle;
            text-align: center; 
            opacity: 0.0;
            transition: opacity 0.2s linear 0s;
            -webkit-transition: opacity 0.2s linear 0s;
            -ms-transition: opacity 0.2s linear 0s;
            -moz-transition: opacity 0.2s linear 0s;
        }
        div#tmp div:hover{
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
            opacity: 0.6;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id='tmp'>
        <div>hello world</div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The transition property defines how elements in html change.
http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp

To alter an element by mouse over you can use the css :hover selector in css.
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_hover.asp

Answer (score 0):

Check out this fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/5tmt98sk/

```
Visit the JS Fiddle page
```

When you are on the jsfiddle page, put your mouse over the image
The website you looked at does the same thing, but there image is the same image, but they photoshop it to be darker, and the photoshop some text on to it.
Same concept =)